# Number of basis of $B_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

So we have $2^3=8$ vectors in $B_3$, but one of them is the zero vector, so the answer should be $\binom 73$. But then there are special cases such as $(1,1,0)^T,(1,0,1)^T,(0,1,1)^T$ that do not form a basis which we need to subtract from the total - how do we count these? Also, how does this generalize to $B_n$?

Comment: There are $28$ unordered bases, and $(7)(6)(4)$ ordered bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick the first two non-zero vectors however you want, then there is one vector, the sum of the first two, that does not complete a basis.  This is because the sum of the first two minus (or plus, they are the same thing here) the third would be zero.

Added after the edit:  for $B_4$ we can pick the first three vectors as above.  It is easiest to consider ordered bases and divide by $4!$ for undordered ones.  To pick the fourth vector, you can't choose the sum of any pair or the sum of all three, so you have seven not allowed.  This approach generates a formula for any given $B_n$,but I don't see how to make one for general $n$.